Termux - Issue with Linking `libc++_shared.so` on with Premake5
I'm trying to build a project using Premake5 on an Android environment, and I'm encountering a linker error related to libc++_shared.so. Below are the details of the problem and what I've tried so far.
Premake5 Configuration
Here is the premake5.lua script I'm using:
local ocgcore_config=function()
    files { "*.h", "*.hpp", "*.cpp", "RNG/*.hpp", "RNG/*.cpp" }
    warnings "Extra"
    cppdialect "C++17"
    rtti "Off"
    
    filter "configurations:Release"
        optimize "Speed"    
    filter "configurations:Debug"
        optimize "Off"
    filter "action:not vs*"
        buildoptions { "-Wno-unused-parameter", "-pedantic" }
    filter "system:linux"
        linkoptions { "-Wl,--no-undefined" }
    filter { "system:macosx", "files:processor_visit.cpp" }
        buildoptions { "-fno-exceptions" }
    filter {}
        include "./lua/"
        links { "lua" }
        includedirs { "lua/src" }
end

if not subproject then
    newoption {
        trigger = "oldwindows",
        description = "Use the v141_xp toolset to support windows XP sp3"
    }
    workspace "ocgcore"
    location "build"
    language "C++"
    objdir "obj"
    configurations { "Debug", "Release" }
    symbols "On"
    staticruntime "on"
    startproject "ocgcoreshared"

    filter "system:windows"
        defines { "WIN32", "_WIN32", "NOMINMAX" }
        platforms {"Win32", "x64", "arm", "arm64"}

    filter "platforms:Win32"
        architecture "x86"

    filter "platforms:x64"
        architecture "x64"

    filter "platforms:arm64"
        architecture "ARM64"

    filter "platforms:arm"
        architecture "ARM"

    filter { "action:vs*", "platforms:Win32 or x64" }
        vectorextensions "SSE2"
        if _OPTIONS["oldwindows"] then
            toolset "v141_xp"
        end

    filter "action:vs*"
        flags "MultiProcessorCompile"

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "_DEBUG"
        targetdir "bin/debug"
        runtime "Debug"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "NDEBUG"
        targetdir "bin/release"

    local function set_target_dir(target,arch)
        filter { "system:windows", "configurations:" .. target, "architecture:" .. arch }
            targetdir("bin/" .. arch .. "/" .. target)
    end

    set_target_dir("debug","x64")
    set_target_dir("debug","arm")
    set_target_dir("debug","arm64")

    set_target_dir("release","x64")
    set_target_dir("release","arm")
    set_target_dir("release","arm64")

    filter { "action:not vs*", "system:windows" }
        buildoptions { "-static-libgcc", "-static-libstdc++", "-static" }
        linkoptions { "-static-libgcc", "-static-libstdc++", "-static" }
        defines { "UNICODE", "_UNICODE" }

    filter { "system:linux" }
        includedirs { "lua/src" }
        linkoptions { "-static-libgcc", "-static-libstdc++" }
    
    filter { "system:android" }
        libdirs { "$(NDK_HOME)/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-aarch64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android" }
        links { "c++_shared" }
        linkoptions { "-L$(NDK_HOME)/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-aarch64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android -lc++_shared" }

    local function disableWinXPWarnings(prj)
        premake.w('<XPDeprecationWarning>false</XPDeprecationWarning>')
    end

    local function vcpkgStaticTriplet202006(prj)
        premake.w('<VcpkgEnabled>false</VcpkgEnabled>')
        premake.w('<VcpkgUseStatic>false</VcpkgUseStatic>')
        premake.w('<VcpkgAutoLink>false</VcpkgAutoLink>')
    end

    require('vstudio')

    premake.override(premake.vstudio.vc2010.elements, "globals", function(base, prj)
        local calls = base(prj)
        table.insertafter(calls, premake.vstudio.vc2010.targetPlatformVersionGlobal, disableWinXPWarnings)
        table.insertafter(calls, premake.vstudio.vc2010.globals, vcpkgStaticTriplet202006)
        return calls
    end)
end

project "ocgcore"
    kind "StaticLib"
    ocgcore_config()

project "ocgcoreshared"
    kind "SharedLib"
    flags "NoImportLib"
--  filter "configurations:Release"
--      flags "LinkTimeOptimization"
--  filter {}
    targetname "ocgcore"
    defines "OCGCORE_EXPORT_FUNCTIONS"
    staticruntime "on"
    visibility "Hidden"
    ocgcore_config()

Environment Variables
I have set the NDK_HOME environment variable in my .bashrc file:
export NDK_HOME=$HOME/android-ndk-r26b

I verified the path by listing the contents:
ls $NDK_HOME/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-aarch64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android | grep libc++_shared.so

The Error
Despite these configurations, I am still encountering the following error:
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lc++_shared
aarch64-linux-android-clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [ocgcoreshared.make:111: ../bin/release/libocgcore.so] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:46: ocgcoreshared] Error 2

What am I missing or doing wrong in this setup? How can I resolve the linker error related to libc++_shared.so?
Thank you for any assistance!

I fixed it with pkg install ndk-multilib
